# How do I format the time values when performing a time personalization in Sitecore?

Tags: personalization, rules-engine

[image]

Am I formatting this correctly or is there a different format to use this correctly?

Comment: This looks like a custom condition. Check what is the class name assigned to it and how it's handled in the background

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore applications and UI dialogs display date & time values in the server time zone. Therefore, you have to convert UTC date/time to server time using the `ToServerTime()` method from the `Sitecore.DateUtil` class. Also
when saving input from a date/time picker to the database ensure that the selected date/time value is converted to UTC before saving by using the `IsoDateToUtcIsoDate()` method from the `Sitecore.DateUtil` class.

More on the date/time best practices in Sitecore please read [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/date-time-best-practices.html).